# Какой есть слушатель на изменение текста в TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, listener

Поступает текст в TextView.

Есть ли какой нибудь способ отследить, прослушать это и поставить событие при изменении текста? (Допустим в TextView был написан текст "Тест 123". Далее текст изменился и стал "Тест 124". возможно ли это отследить и повесить своё событие (действие)?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

Создайте глобальную переменную `String stringChange = "";`

```
mTextView.addTextChangedListener ( new TextWatcher () {

    public void afterTextChanged ( Editable s ) {

        //что-то делаем после изменения
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged ( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after ) {

        //что-то делаем до изменения
    }

    public void onTextChanged ( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count ) {

        //что-то делаем при изменении
        //будем проверять изменилось ли значение, а именно текст
            if (stringChange.equals(s.toString())) {

                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "содержимое не изменилось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                stringChange= s.toString();

                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, stringChange, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Я пробывал так, но он делает действие бесконечное кол-во раз. Например если я поставлю показ Toast , то он показывается постоянно

Comment: @Антон в onTextChanged показывайте, в afterTextChanged скрывайте. Опять же как именно вы реализуете мне не видно

Comment: @Антон: покажите как меняете текст, как выводите Toast

Comment: текст меняется автоматически, это метаданные с сервера приходят (название текущего играющего трека на радио)

Comment: @Антон: возможно вы обновляете textView постоянно, а не когда меняется реально значение?

Comment: возможно. Но разве сервер не выгнал бы меня за слишком частые обращения к нему? если я так часто запросы посылал бы...

Comment: @Антон: обновил ответ

Comment: before = s.toString(); подчеркивает пунктиром красным. Пишет мол, Required: int, Found: java.lang.String

Comment: @Антон а понял, там же параметры before. сейчас обновлю

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую активити, не вылазил Toast ? А то между активити перехожу, и Toast каждый раз вылазиет